# Is it possible to run iOS on a non-iOS device?

Tags: ios

Theoretically, is it possible to run iOS on a device that doesn't ship with it? I know that Apple signed iOS so it only runs on Apple devices, but is there any hack that could potentially change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically? Sure, but it'd be a challenge, and I don't think anyone's done it.

However, you can sort of get it running on a Mac if you have Xcode: Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator. This will load a simulator for the iPhone with Photos, Contacts, Settings, Game Center, Maps, Newsstand, Passbook, and Safari. No way to install apps (other than making them yourself in Xcode).

Comment: Okay thanks. BTW is xcode pricy? free how much? developer account?

Comment: XCode is free.  A developer account is $99/year.

Comment: @DumbProducts A L said something you might have missed that is very important: there is **no way to install apps that you haven't made yourself**.

Comment: @Jason (BTW I have an iPod touch running iOS 6 but this is just for fun. :)) You don't need a developer account to run the simulator, right?

Comment: right, the developer account is only need to deploy to an actual device